# Settings file is not generated in .NET 5 and 6

Tags: .net-5, .net-6.0

In .NET 4, to create a settings file (`[name].exe.config`) I would just add a `Settings.settings` file to the project by adding a `Settings File` from the `Add New Item` dialog box. Then, after building, the `[name].exe.config` file was generated together with the exe file in the output folder. (For some reason there was also a `App.config` added to the project.)

With .NET 5 and 6 a understand that the settings file is named `[name].dll.config` instead, but when following the procedure mentioned above this file isn't generated. (An `App.config` file is also not added to the project.)

So my question is how to generate a settings file in a windows desktop app targeting .NET 6.

Comment: It is a bit clunky, the order you do this is important, *first* add the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager Nuget package, *then* use Project > Add New Item > Application Configuration File, then add the Settings File.  Getting app.config first ensures it contains the required entries to support the settings.

Comment: I followed your instructions. The `[name].dll.config` is now generated but it is empty. The `app.config` only contains `<configuration></configuration>`. It  does not reflect the changes made to the `Settings` file. Anything I missed?

Comment: Are you supposed to configure System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in some way? Or does it do its work just by being referenced as a dependency?

Comment: I guess you added the existing setting file.  Nope, you must use Project > Add New Item > Setting File and re-enter the settings.

Comment: It works now when I first add the files to the root project folder. Earlier I added them to the Properties folder/namespace. I managed to move the settings file to the Properties folder/namespace by manually editing the files plus the proj file. But as soon as I move the app.config to the Properties folder, app.config no longer reflects the changes made in settings file. Anyway I'll just keep the app.config in the root proj folder. 
Thank you. I consider this question answered.